# Want to log in on the Django side and also be logged in on the Vue side

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django app with some pages and then I use Django Rest Framework to supply data to a Vue application, including loggin the user in. The Django website and the Vue application are not on the same domain or server or country or universe for that matter. I want to know how can I make it that if I log in on the Django side and I am redirected to the Vue app that I am also logged in on the Vue side? And visa versa if I log in on the Vue side that I am also logged in on the Django side.

I am using JWT authentication and I thought about sending the token to the page (Django side if logged in on Vue side) I go to after being logged in but this seems to be impossible to do, or I just cannot find an answer of how to do it.

Comment: seems like SSO (single sign-on). I guess SSO depends on one auth server. it's not like login into any server and getting access to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DRF's Simple JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) on the backend side.

On the Vue side, you must create a flow to log in the user and save the token in the local storage or some global context. You should also create a context that catches any 401 -> 403 to refresh the token or to forward the user to login again.

You may take a look at [this example project](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/drf-SimpleJWT-Vue) from an author of the library.

Comment: Why would I need to log in on the Vue side again when I am logged in on the Django side that is the whole point of my question. I want to send the token from the Django side to the Vue side so it automatically logs the user in on the Vue side and gets his information based on the token, which seems the only way to do it is sending the token in the URL which is insecure. So login information cannot be shared between two sites or even a domain and a sub domain?

Comment: @crawlingdev You enter creds in Form which is rendered using vue js. creds sent to the Django server. django returns jwt token if the creds are valid. then you make requests to APIs to Django including that token in payload if API requires authentication. That's how jwt works.